# Equivalence relations and their class

Tags: equivalence-relations

I am trying to figure out how to prove that an equivalence relation of the relation *x~y* defined on **Z** <=> **x-y** is a multiple of 3.

My attempt was:

1) **Reflexive**: *x = x* *=> x ~ x*

2) **Symmetric**: *x ~ y => x - y => - y + x => y ~ x*

3) **Transitive**: ... <--- how do I make use of the fact that **x-y** is a multiple of 3?

Thanks for help!

Comment: "x = x => x ~ x" What do you mean? This proves nothing. "x - y = - y + x => (x,y) ~ (y,x)" What does this mean? (x,y) ~ (y,x) is not even defined since ~ is a relation between numbers, not pairs of numbers.

Comment: Can be useful if you specify what numbers you are using : natural, integer, rational...

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA it would appear pretty clear that this is modular arithmetic on the naturals. Surely if someone was doing otherwise they would specify for thats a bit more advanced.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I don't exactly understand the question, but it is clear if someone was dealing with an equivalence relation like this on a set other than the integers they would say so.

Comment: On the line that begins "Symmetric", you have a statement implying a number, which in turn implies another number, which implies a statement.  Implication makes sense only between two statements, so none of the implications on that line make sense.

Answer (score 8):

You have not proven anything.

$x-x=0$ is a multiple of $3$, so it is reflexive.

If $x-y=3k$ for some integer $k$, then $y-x=-3k$ is a multiple of $3$, so it is symmetric.

If $x-y=3m$ for some integer $m$ and $y-z=3n$ for some integer $n$, then $x-z=3(m+n)$ is a multiple of $3$, so it is transitive.